# Несколько статичных внешних IP

Tags: сеть

Доброго времени суток.

Ситуация: есть 100 Mb/s utp от ISP идет сразу в ethernet карту на машине-шлюзе. Соответственно данная карта "получает" конфигурацию под один внешний статичный IP. 
На этой же машине еще "висят" пару интерфейсов для раздачи инета на внутренние свитчи для локальных юзверей.

Вопрос: требуется арендовать еще несколько внешних статичных IP от этого же ISP. Как их корректно "вписать" при существующем раскладе? Вешать все на одно устройство и разруливать мршрутизацией? Или воткнуть в промежуток между шлюзом и кабелем от провайдера какой-нибудь хитрый девайс, который будет разруливать трафик на разные порты по типу один вход и 4 выхода (для 4 статичных IP адреса)?
Подскажите есть ли такие девайсы, гуру сисадмины.

Спасибо за любые подсказки.

Comment: Что по итогу надо? Балансировка, резервирование, будут протянуты доп.кабели, или все ip будут на одной физике?

Comment: устройства марки Микротик имеют широкие возможности по настройке сети и стоят не дорого. Вы пробовали?

Comment: если входящий кабель один не вижу никакого смысла делать более одного интерфейса. Но дальше все зависит от того, как пров отдаст вам ip. либо он дает вам сразу подсеть, в которой состоит и тот ip, что у вас сейчас. и тогда вы должны поднять у себя эти ip алиасами или использовать arp_proxy. Либо пров может отдать вам подсеть новых адресов, указав ваш основной ip как шлюз для них, тогда вам будет легко маршрутизировать их на другие машины у себя внутри. в общем тут все зависит исключительно от того, что вам надо делать с этими адресами и каким образом пров готов вам их отдать

Comment: @CuprumBur Зачем микротик, если есть машина-шлюз, которая сама может разрулить все что угодно.

Comment: @defrag доп кабелей от ISP больше не будет, он просто выделяет несколько белых IP а дальше "крутись как хочешь". Да, все IP на одной utp'шке

Comment: @CuprumBur если девайсы микротика решат эту задачу,то обязательно попробую

Comment: @Mike подсетка не нужна, избыточна. Общее количество внешних статиков нужно не более 4 под все нужды моего сегмента предприятия. Ваше решение при таком раскладе? Сделать алиасы на один интерфейс всех четырех IP и разруливать маршрутизацией и iptables?

Comment: Почитайте [Гайд](https://spw.ru/forum/threads/nastrojka-marshrutizatora-mikrotik-rb951g-2hnd-na-neskolko-vneshnix-ip-adresov.765/)

Comment: @CuprumBur спасибо за ссылку, надо вкурить повнимательнее.

Comment: @Spouk провайдеры редко дают отдельные адреса, что бы дать вам 1 адрес провайдер должен для это выделить подсеть в 4 адреса. гораздо проще выделить одну подсеть из 8 адресов, 6 из которых вы сможете использовать (и еще 2 при очень большом желании, хотя это и нарушает некоторые стандарты). И да, под "сеткой" я разумеется имею ввиду подсеть достаточного для вас размера, т.е. 4 или 8 адресов, а не какую нибудь класса C. И вы так и не сказали где будут эти остальные статики, они нужны вам на самом маршрутизаторе или на машинах внутри сети. Это основной вопрос, от него зависит что просить у прова

Comment: @Spouk Если у вас на маршрутизаторе linux, то в микротике точно нет никакой надобности, потому на нем точно такой же linux с немного измененной системой команд для работы с маршрутизацией и iptables.

Comment: @Mike внутри сети, для шлюза нужен один, все остальные пойдут на решение разных задач www,email,dns/ns,samba etc...

Comment: @Mike да на шлюзе убунта, хотел склонить руководство на фряху, т.к. моя основная рабочая лошадка, они отказали, пока что :)

Comment: Тогда если вы попросите у прова промаршрутизировать подсеть из этих 4х адресов через ваш текущий ip шлюза, то сможете поднять эту подсеть на внутренней сетевухе и спокойно отдать на целевые машины (1 ip из этой подсети вам скорее всего придется поставить на самом маршрутизаторе, хотя можно сделать ход конем, расширив маску и поставив ip за пределами этой подсети). Т.е. вам надо будет только поднять ip с нужной маской, алиасом на внутренней сетевухе (ну или на отдельной или на vlan, в случае если внутренние сервера с реальниками можно подключить отдельным линком).

Comment: Вот если ваш пров не сможет/не захочет так делать, а отдаст просто подсетку, типа втыкайте свои компы непосредственно в нее, вот тогда надо будет немного поизвращаться, что бы они попали внутрь сети (думаю включения proxy_arp на сетевухе в сторону прова и маршрутизации внутрь сети будет достаточно)

Comment: @Mike спасибо за подсказки, надо обдумать и продумать как лучше это все реализовать в оконцовке.

Comment: @Spouk вопрос чисто личного интереса. Почему все это (www, dns, email) не реализовать на одном белом ip, с применением того же PAT-a (port mapping)?

Comment: @defrag такой вариант тоже входит в список рассматриваемых, просто задача была поставлена проработать все возможные варианты с разных позиций. Вот и приходится все подготавливать. PAT наиболее логичный и просто путь во всех аспектах и безопасность, и управление, и контроль, однако задача предполагает наличие более одного варианта.